# Can I pass results of a QUERY as arguments to a Function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count the number of days between ranges for people (aka days off and whatnot). I have a query like this that works:

```
=SUM(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    DAYS(
      QUERY($A$2:$D$100, "SELECT C WHERE A='Dave' AND B >= date '2024-01-01' AND C <= date '2024-01-31'"), 
      QUERY($A$2:$D$100, "SELECT B WHERE A='Dave' AND B >= date '2024-01-01' AND C <= date '2024-01-31'")
    )
  )
)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do `DAYS(SOMEFUNCTION(QUERY(SELECT C,B)))` such that it takes the two columns output from `QUERY` and throws it as two arguments into `DAYS`. I tried `TRANSPOSE` and `ARRAYFORMULA`, but clearly I don't understand them 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```cpp
=FILTER(C2:C-B2:B,A2:A="Dave",B2:B>=--"2024-01-01",C2:C<=--"2024-01-31"))
```

Comment: That does not work since these are dates, hence me using `DAYS`. I get back `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: Can't perform the function difference on values that are not numbers`

Comment: I tried changing my format from 2/5/24 in the cell to actually 2024-02-05. Should I be using math in the query to convert the format to something that can understand B-C, which would take away the need to use `DAYS`?

Comment: dates in Sheets are just numbers, but apparently QUERY doesn't see them as numbers, I recommend using FILTER instead, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `LET`:

```
=LET(arr,QUERY($A$2:$D$100, "SELECT C,B WHERE A='Dave' AND B >= date '2024-01-01' AND C <= date '2024-01-31'"),sd,INDEX(arr,0,2),ed,INDEX(arr,0,1),ARRAYFORMULA(DAYS(ed,sd)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no inbuilt spread operator. You have to use `INDEX` to index into the range and create the spread:

```
LAMBDA(cols,DAYS(INDEX(cols,,1),INDEX(cols,,2)))
```

```
=LET(
  spreadFunc,
    LAMBDA(cols,DAYS(INDEX(cols,,1),INDEX(cols,,2))),
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    spreadFunc(
      QUERY($A$2:$D$100, 
         "SELECT C, B WHERE A='Dave' AND B >= date '2024-01-01' AND C <= date '2024-01-31'"
       )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the need to use `days` if you use the *datediff* scalar function within `query` to extract the date ranges from columns B&C. Note that your input dates must be in ISO (yyyy-mm-dd) format in order for `query` to understand them. If this is the case you can try:

```
=sum(query($A$2:$D$100,"select datediff(C,B) where A='Dave' and B >= date '2024-01-01' and C <= date '2024-01-31'"))
```